# PHP move_uploaded_file mysterious issue

Tags: php, file, upload

My code allows for a .jpg file to be uploaded.  Our test .jpg file is only 200kb and easily falls within our file limit of a couple of meg.  We check for errors following the call to move_uploaded_file as seen below.

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file['tmp_name'], MEMBER_UPLOADS_DIR . "/{$dir_name}/{$file_name}") {
list out the errors - shown for simplicity
}
```

Occasionally the code indicates there are no errors.  Yet when I check folder for the file, it does not exist.

Debug attempts also indicate no error has occurred.

Is there something else I should be checking to ensure the upload actually succeeded?

I should add that if you attempt the same operation immediately afterwards with the exact same file, it works.

We are confounded by this one.

Comment: Check `$uploaded_file['error']` Before doing anything else with the uploaded file [See the manual example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 0):

Further analysis showed an error in our code prior to the call to move_uploaded_file.  In some instances our code was jumping over the call.

Thanks for the feedback.